# Homotopy classification of maps into nilmanifolds

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, nilpotent-groups

I am interested in answers or reference in the literature to the following problem:

> Classify up to homotopy all maps $A\to X$, where $A$ is a closed oriented manifold and $X$ is a closed nilmanifold of the same dimension as $A$.

Of course by "classify'' here we mean describe a complete set of invariants to distinguish between maps up to homotopy, for instance in terms of cohomology.

Recall that a nilmanifold is an aspherical manifold whose fundamental group is [nilpotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_group) and torsion-free. One can build its refined Postnikov tower directly from the lower central series of the fundamental group, as in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/33833/what-is-a-principal-refinement-of-a-postnikov-system). This exhibits the nilmanifold as an iterated principal torus bundle.

For this reason I feel that the problem may be approachable. For instance, if $X$ is an abelian nilmanifold (ie a torus) then a map $A\to X$ is classified by a tuple of elements of $H^1(A;\mathbb{Z})$.

Meanwhile, I am well aware that solutions to problems of this type usually exist only in the case where $X$ is simply-connected, and without this assumption things become considerably more complicated.

I would be happy with an answer in the simplest non-trivial case, ie when $X$ is the $3$-dimensional [Heisenberg manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_homotopy_theory#Formal_spaces).

Comment: The answer is contained in your post: $[A,X]=Hom(\pi_1(A),\pi_1(X))$, i.e. such homotopy classes are classified by (fundamental) group homomorphisms. In particular, if $X$ or $A$ is simply connected you only have the trivial map, and if $X$ is the $3$-dimensional Heisenberg manifold, you only need to look at homomorphisms to the discrete Heisenberg group.

Comment: @Fernando: $Hom(\pi_1(A), \pi_1(X))$ corresponds to based 
maps, which surjects to $[A,X]$. Do you know that the action of $\pi_1(X)$ is trivial when $\pi_1(X)$ is non-abelian? 

Comment: @Fernando: You are right in the based case (and this is Proposition 1B.9 in Hatcher). This was silly oversight on my part. @Paul: I think the action is by conjugation. So the set of unbased homotopy classes should be the set of homomorphisms modulo conjugation. Thanks both!

Answer (score 3):

This is not a complete answer, but I can say something on the $3$-dimensional case. The Heisenberg manifold $Z$ is the circle bundle $Z \to T^2$ of Chern class $1$. Thus there is a (homotopy) fibration

$$Z \to T^2 \to CP^{\infty}.$$

Let's say you want based maps. For any space $X$, you get a fibre sequence

$$map_+ (X;Z) \to map_+ (X;T^2) \to map (X;CP^{\infty}$$

of mapping spaces. It is easy to see that there are homotopy equivalences $map(X,T^2) \simeq H^1 (X;\pi_1 (T^2))$ and $map (X;CP^{\infty}) \simeq H^2 (X) \times BH^1 (X)$; the latter one is not natural in $X$.

Therefore the long exact homotopy sequence yields

$$0 \to H^1 (X)  \to [X,Z ]_+ \to H^1 (X; \pi_1 (T^2)) \to H^2 (X).$$

The third map is not a group homomorphism; it sends an element represented by a homotopy class $X \to T^2$ to the Chern class of the pullback bundle. The first map is the action of $H^1 (X)=[X,T^1]$ given by the $T^1$-action on the fibres of $Z \to T^2$. We see that this action is free.

An interesting special case might be $X=T^3$. Here $H^1 (X,\pi_1 (T^2))$ is the abelian group of all $2 \times 3$-matrices, and the map to $H^2 (T^3)= \Lambda^2 \mathbb{Z}^3$ (the group of skewsymmetric $3 \times 3$-matrices) is given by $A \mapsto A^t J A$, with

$$J=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 
1 & 0\end{pmatrix}.$$

Thus there is the following result:

Proposition: ''If $X=T^3$, the action of $H^1 (X;T)$ on the set $[X,Z]_+$ is free and the set of orbits can be identified with the solution set of $A^t J A =0$ in the group of $2 \times 3$-matrices.''